# What are the best practices for using cronjob along with docker and laravel?

Tags: laravel, docker, cron, laravel-9

I ran into a problem that I have to manually write a cronjob in a production environment inside Ubuntu, I would like to have a completely standalone docker project. There is a solution with creating an ubuntu container, but it looks weird, ubuntu inside ubuntu. So far, I've had to set up a cronjob outside of a container on Ubuntu itself.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      apt-utils \
      libpq-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      libzip-dev \
      zip unzip \
      git && \
      docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
      docker-php-ext-install bcmath && \
      docker-php-ext-install gd && \
      docker-php-ext-install zip && \
      apt-get clean && \
      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY ./_docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

# Install composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --filename=composer \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin

WORKDIR /var/www
```

docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
      - ./_docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - 8876:80
    container_name: flowers_nginx
    depends_on:
        -   flowers

  flowers:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: _docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
    depends_on:
        -   database
    container_name: flowers_php

  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./temp/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ****
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
        MYSQL_USER: ****
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****
    ports:
      - 8101:3306
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
    container_name: flowers_mysql
```

Due to lack of experience, I need a hint with the best solution, maybe use kubernetes-cronjob or redis, but I have not yet learned these technologies, I will be grateful if you help me choose the right solution and development path.

I tried to do the following inside Ubuntu itself which has docker installed and it works, but because of this I can't make a completely standalone docker project without connecting to the ubuntu job which has docker installed

`crontab -e`

`* * * * * cd /var/www/public/flowers_shop && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`